# how to check if front page is set to show a static page

Tags: conditional-tags

I need to determine whether the reading settings are set to use a static page or the latest post for the front page.

Is there a conditional that will return true if the front page is set to show a static page? I don't need to check what page the static page might be, just if its a static page at all.

For this scenario would it be correct to use:

```
if( is_front_page() && !is_home() ){
   // seems we're on the front but not on the blog home,
   // so it must be a static page..
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your conditional logic makes sense as well but you're probably looking for this:

```
if ( 'page' == get_option('show_on_front') ) {
   // do something
}
```

Hint: You can append `options.php` to the WordpPress admin url like this:
`http://www.example.com/wp-admin/options.php` to see all options.
*( that's where I found the answer for you .)*

Comment: Nailed it! Just a suggestion: the WordPress coding standards recommend using "Yoda" casing, e.g. `if ( 'page' == get_option( 'show_on_front' ) )`. I recommend getting into this habit, as it helps isolate the effect of a syntax error in which the `==` operator is replaced by the `=` operator.